# Users cannot login to Windows 10 machine with their AzureAD account via RDP

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop, azure-activedirectory

I just built a Windows 10 VM for our developers to use for some testing.  I logged in via the Virtual Console with my AAD account and joined it to the AzureAD Domain.  I then enabled RDP and tested it. I was able to login using `AzureAD\myemailaddress`.  I gave a developer the IP and had him try. He could not log in.  I manually added him under "Other Users > Work or School Users".  He still could not login via RDP.  I had him log in via the Virtual Console and it worked. It prompted him to set up Windows Hello.  Once he did that I logged him out and had him test RDP again. It still did not work.  I added him to the remote desktop users group.  Still no luck.  There are no errors or warnings in the event viewer > security log.  If I intentionally type in the wrong password I do see an event for "Unknown user name or bad password." but the `Security ID` is `NULL SID`.  With the correct password, the user just sees "Login attempt failed"

Updated to 20H2. Same issue.  I had another developer try. Same issue.

What is going on?  Why can I log in but nobody else?

Comment: Azure Active Directory has been down for many around a day ago. Maybe that's caused the issue? What error message do they get when they try to login?

Comment: "Login attempt failed". Updated question.